# Trying to set up an API from anki to export card information from my deck

Tags: python, json

I am receiving:

```
TypeError: invoke() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

after running:

```
import json
import urllib.request

def request(action, **params):
    return {'action': action, 'params': params, 'version': 6}

def invoke(action, **params):
    requestJson = json.dumps(request(action, **params)).encode('utf-8')
    response = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request('http://localhost:8765',         requestJson)))
    if len(response) != 2:
    raise Exception('response has an unexpected number of fields')
    if 'error' not in response:
    raise Exception('response is missing required error field')
    if 'result' not in response:
    raise Exception('response is missing required result field')
    if response['error'] is not None:
    raise Exception(response['error'])
    return response['result']


result = invoke('deckNames')
print('got list of decks: {}'.format(result))
Info = invoke('cardsInfo', 1)
```

I tried to add self to the def of the invoke function but then it returns:

```
TypeError: invoke() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action'
```

Comment: (1) The `invoke` signature accepts one positional argument and an arbitrary number of named arguments (keyword arguments). (2) Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: If you use `**params`, you have to give additional arguments with keywords. Try `*params` instead.